# Image Url is stored in Realm from camera and gallery intent but not seen in listview

Tags: android, realm, picasso

**My Activity class:**

```
public class CommonChattingAttachmentActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity {

    Realm realm;
    RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener;
    CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;
    EditText descEditTxt;
    boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
    String userChoosenTask;
    TextView descTxt;
    ImageView imgallery, imgcam, img;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1888;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE = 1889;
    ImageView imgattach;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_chatting_attachment);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        //img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        //descTxt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdesc);
        //INITIALIZE REALM
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        setAdapter();
        displayInputDialog();
        imgcam = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcam);
        imgallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imggallery);
        imgattach = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgattach);
        imgallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                galleryIntent();
            }
        });
        imgcam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraIntent();
            }
        });
        imgattach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

    }

    public void setAdapter() {
        //lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        final CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        helper.retrieveFromDB();
        adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(this, helper.justRefresh());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, helper.justRefresh());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    private void setAdapters() {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        //INITIALIZE REALM
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        helper.retrieveFromDB();
        adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(this, helper.justRefresh());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, helper.justRefresh());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    //DISPLAY INPUT DIALOG
    public void displayInputDialog() {

        //EDITTEXTS
        descEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editwrite);
        ImageView fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.send);

        //SAVE
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // descTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String desc = descEditTxt.getText().toString();
                CommonChat s = new CommonChat();
                s.setDescription(desc);
                CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
                if(helper.save(s)) {
                    descEditTxt.setText("");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


        });
    }

    public void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    public void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
    }

    public void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
                if(items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                    if(result) {
                        cameraIntent();
                    }
                } else if(items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                    if(result) {
                        galleryIntent();
                    }
                } else if(items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo")) {
                        cameraIntent();
                    } else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library")) {
                        galleryIntent();
                    }
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            } else if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if(data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(bm));
        setAdapters();
    }

    public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(destination));
        setAdapters();
    }

    public void SaveImageVideoData(String data) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
            // obj.setExtensionTypeValue(stringMediaExtType);
            s.setImageUrl(data);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            setAdapters();
            Log.d("path", data);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

**My Adapter Class**

```
public class CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter
        extends BaseAdapter {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<CommonChat> CommonChats;

    public CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<CommonChat> CommonChats) {
        this.c = c;
        this.CommonChats = CommonChats;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CommonChats.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return CommonChats.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.item_commonchat, parent, false);
        }


        TextView descTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textdesc);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);


        final CommonChat s = (CommonChat) this.getItem(position);

        if(descTxt != null) {
            descTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            descTxt.setText(s.getDescription());
        }


        String imageUrl = s.getImageUrl();

        if(imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 0) {
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            descTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Picasso.with(c).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(img);

        } else {

            Picasso.with(c).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(img);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**My RealmHelper Class:**

```
 public class CommonChatRealmHelper {

    Realm realm;
    RealmResults<CommonChat> CommonChats;
    Boolean saved = null;

    public CommonChatRealmHelper(Realm realm) {
        this.realm = realm;
    }

    //WRITE
    public Boolean save(final CommonChat CommonChat) {
        if(CommonChat == null) {
            saved = false;
        } else {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {

                    try {
                        CommonChat s = realm.copyToRealm(CommonChat);

                        saved = true;

                    } catch(RealmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        saved = false;
                    }

                }
            });
        }


        return saved;
    }

    //READ
    public void retrieveFromDB() {
        CommonChats = realm.where(CommonChat.class).findAll();
    }

    // REFRESH
    public ArrayList<CommonChat> justRefresh() {
        ArrayList<CommonChat> latest = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CommonChat s : CommonChats) {
            latest.add(s);
            Log.d("Testing", String.valueOf(s));
        }
        return latest;
    }
}
```

> Blockquote 10-06 10:46:40.735 24930-24930/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/Testing: CommonChat = [{description:null},{imageUrl:/storage/emulated/0/1507267000613.jpg}]
>   10-06 10:46:40.745 24930-24930/com.xitiz.xitizmobile D/path: /storage/emulated/0/1507267000613.jpg

```
 **My Edited Code Snippet of URI**

public class CommonChattingAttachmentActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity {

    Realm realm;
    RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener;
    CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;
    EditText descEditTxt;
    boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
    String userChoosenTask;
    TextView descTxt;
    ImageView imgallery, imgcam, img;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1888;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE = 1889;
    ImageView imgattach;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_chatting_attachment);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        //img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        //descTxt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdesc);
        //INITIALIZE REALM
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        setAdapter();
        displayInputDialog();
        imgcam = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcam);
        imgallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imggallery);
        imgattach = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgattach);
        imgallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                galleryIntent();
            }
        });
        imgcam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraIntent();
            }
        });
        imgattach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

    }

    public void setAdapter() {
        //lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        final CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        helper.retrieveFromDB();
        adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(this, helper.justRefresh());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, helper.justRefresh());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    private void setAdapters() {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        //INITIALIZE REALM
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        helper.retrieveFromDB();
        adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(this, helper.justRefresh());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
                adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, helper.justRefresh());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    //DISPLAY INPUT DIALOG
    public void displayInputDialog() {

        //EDITTEXTS
        descEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editwrite);
        ImageView fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.send);

        //SAVE
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // descTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String desc = descEditTxt.getText().toString();
                CommonChat s = new CommonChat();
                s.setDescription(desc);
                CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
                if(helper.save(s)) {
                    descEditTxt.setText("");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


        });
    }

    public void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    public void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
    }

    public void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
                if(items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                    if(result) {
                        cameraIntent();
                    }
                } else if(items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                    if(result) {
                        galleryIntent();
                    }
                } else if(items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo")) {
                        cameraIntent();
                    } else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library")) {
                        galleryIntent();
                    }
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            } else if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if(data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(bm));
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(myUri));


        // setAdapters();
    }

    public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(destination));
        // setAdapters();
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(destination));
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(myUri));
    }

    public void SaveImageVideoData(String data) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
            // obj.setExtensionTypeValue(stringMediaExtType);
            s.setImageUrl(data);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            setAdapters();
            Log.d("path", data);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this code

```
public class CommonChattingAttachmentActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity {

    Realm realm;
    //RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener;
    CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter adapter;
    ListView lv;
    EditText descEditTxt;
    boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
    String userChoosenTask;
    TextView descTxt;
    ImageView imgallery, imgcam, img;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1888;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE = 1889;
    ImageView imgattach;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_chatting_attachment);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        //img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        //descTxt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textdesc);
        //INITIALIZE REALM
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        setAdapter();
        displayInputDialog();
        imgcam = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcam);
        imgallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imggallery);
        imgattach = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgattach);
        imgallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                galleryIntent();
            }
        });
        imgcam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cameraIntent();
            }
        });
        imgattach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

    }

    public void setAdapter() {
        //lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        //final CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
        //helper.retrieveFromDB();
        //adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(this, helper.justRefresh());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        //    @Override
        //    public void onChange() {
        //        adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, helper.justRefresh());
       //         lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       //         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       //     }
       // };
       // realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    private void setAdapters() {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
        //INITIALIZE REALM
       // realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        //final CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
       // helper.retrieveFromDB();
       // adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(this, helper.justRefresh());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       // realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        //    @Override
       //     public void onChange() {
        //        adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, helper.justRefresh());
        //        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //    }
        //};
        //realm.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    //DISPLAY INPUT DIALOG
    public void displayInputDialog() {

        //EDITTEXTS
        descEditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editwrite);
        ImageView fab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.send);

        //SAVE
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // descTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String desc = descEditTxt.getText().toString();
                CommonChat s = new CommonChat();
                s.setDescription(desc);
                CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
                if(helper.save(s)) {
                    descEditTxt.setText("");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this, "Invalid Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


        });
    }

    public void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    public void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
    }

    public void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(CommonChattingAttachmentActivity.this);
                if(items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                    if(result) {
                        cameraIntent();
                    }
                } else if(items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                    if(result) {
                        galleryIntent();
                    }
                } else if(items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo")) {
                        cameraIntent();
                    } else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library")) {
                        galleryIntent();
                    }
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            } else if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if(data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(bm));
        setAdapters();
    }

    public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SaveImageVideoData(String.valueOf(destination));
        setAdapters();
    }

    public void SaveImageVideoData(String data) {
        try {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            CommonChat s = realm.createObject(CommonChat.class);
            // obj.setExtensionTypeValue(stringMediaExtType);
            s.setImageUrl(data);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
            setAdapters();
            Log.d("path", data);
            Log.d("working realm", "yes....");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter
        extends BaseAdapter {

    Context c;
    // ArrayList<CommonChat> CommonChats;

    // @Override
    // public int getCount() {
    //     return CommonChats.size();
    // }

    // @Override
    // public Object getItem(int position) {
    //     return CommonChats.get(position);
    // }

    // @Override
    // public long getItemId(int position) {
    //     return position;
    // }
```

and

```
 public class CommonChatRealmHelper {

     Realm realm;
   //  RealmResults<CommonChat> CommonChats;
   //  Boolean saved = null;

     public CommonChatRealmHelper(Realm realm) {
         this.realm = realm;
     }

    // WRITE
     public Boolean save(final CommonChat CommonChat) {
         if(CommonChat == null) {
             saved = false;
         } else {
             realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                 @Override
                 public void execute(Realm realm) {

                     try {
                         CommonChat s = realm.copyToRealm(CommonChat);

                         saved = true;

                     } catch(RealmException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                         saved = false;
                     }

                 }
             });
         }


         return saved;
     }

  //   //READ
  //   public void retrieveFromDB() {
  //       CommonChats = realm.where(CommonChat.class).findAll();
  //   }

  //   // REFRESH
  //   public ArrayList<CommonChat> justRefresh() {
  //       ArrayList<CommonChat> latest = new ArrayList<>();
   //      for(CommonChat s : CommonChats) {
  //           latest.add(s);
  //           Log.d("Testing", String.valueOf(s));
  //       }
  //       return latest;
 //    }
  }
```

---

You should do:

```
public class CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter
        extends RealmBaseAdapter { // from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters
   public CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<ChatCommon> results) {
        super(results);
   }
```

and

```
public void setAdapter() {
    //lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listview_common);
    //final CommonChatRealmHelper helper = new CommonChatRealmHelper(realm);
    //helper.retrieveFromDB();
    adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(realm.where(CommonChat.class).findAll());
    //adapter = new CommonChattingAttachmentCustomAdapter(this, helper.justRefresh());
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

See which code was commented out, that should generally be deleted entirely

Answer (score 2):

You need to first convert your image url to a Uri, and then load it using Picasso the same way you did. 
As I am seeing in the log you are using just the same url string in the load method parameter. So kindly convert image url (String) to Uri and then try it. 
Hope this will work. Please do update.

Comment: I tried the way you said but it's not working.Please help me out as i am very new with the concept of Realm

Comment: Its not about realm, its about uri, can you put code snippet here for Uri stuff?